# Undefined function wp_set_password

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I'm creating a plugin. I'm receiving the following error (WP 3.5):

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_set_password() in \path\to\plugin.php on line 18
```

Line 18 consists of simply:

```
wp_set_password( 'newpass', $user_id );
```

This is located in the main plugin file, and all other code has been commented out in order to try and seclude this error. I have no idea why it's showing up as undefined.

Am I missing something here?:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password

Thanks

Comment: what action do you call this on?

Comment: I'm not calling it through an action. I originally had it placed inside of a function, but I received the error. So I placed it in the file all by itself and am still receiving the error. I've even manually defined the function (code here: http://wpseek.com/wp_set_password/), but then I receive an error stating that `wp_hash_password` is undefined.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your plugin loads, pluggable functions aren't loaded yet, in fact a lot of stuff is not loaded yet, this what [actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) are for. Hook your function to an action, like `plugins_loaded` or `init`, when the WP environment is loaded and initialized:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa80246_init' );

function wpa80246_init(){
    wp_set_password( 'newpass', $user_id );
}
```

Comment: Makes sense now. That had crossed my mind, but I couldn't find anything to back the thought up online. Now that I know the entire pluggable file is not loaded until init, it should help with a lot of future problems as well :) Thanks